# Deleting frames from a video as I add new ones

Tags: python, opencv

I'm detecting if the camera can see an object in openCV. I want to record the last 10 seconds the object was in scene. I thought about making 2-3 separate videos and deleting and rewriting as it goes. How would that be performance wise? Or is there a way I can keep one video at a set number of frames? I should add that I'm pretty new to openCV

Comment: Keep a rolling buffer of up to (FPS * 10) frames, discarding the oldest ones when the buffer is full; when the object disappears, write the buffer's contents out to a video file.

Comment: @AKX I had no idea what buffers were. I did some research and no one seems to talk about what they are. I think you mean a circular buffer and that is the thing I'm looking for. Thank you.